Invalid access token received from google oauth
I am trying to implement oauth2 with google and I receive an invalid access token from the token_endpoint.
These are the url's and endpoints I use.
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
GOOGLE_SECRET = os.getenv("GOOGLE_SECRET")
GOOGLE_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?"
GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?"
GOOGLE_SCOPE = "openid"
GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:8050/google-callback"

This is the code I have written to make a call to the token_endpoint:
def get_access_token(url: str, token_url: str, client_id: str, redirect_uri, client_secret=None) -> str:
    """Calls the oauth server and gets the access token based on the code"""
    query_params = urlparse(url).query
    code = parse_qs(query_params)['code'][0]
    body = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "grant_type": AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri
    }

    if client_secret is not None:
        body['client_secret'] = client_secret

    response = requests.post(url=token_url, data=body)
    access_token = response.json()['access_token']
    return access_token

This is how I decode the token in my callback function:
@server.route("/google-callback")
def google_callback_route():
    access_token = get_access_token(request.full_path, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL, GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI, GOOGLE_SECRET)
    decoded_token = jwt.decode(options={'verify_signature': False}, jwt=access_token, algorithms=["RS256"])
    print(decoded_token)



After making the request I get a 200 response and this is the access_token I received:
ya29.a0Ad52N3-2qdB7R3aueWNS9suZOnhInzqQnQqG1z6fYMYkZEkc3rPgdE4haXIJqP8DF-oEwvQiYAx7c8jx3JTyC6FQo9aSnz6dl9EPxUq3q4dUd9p8gYPIApLpoqN7CZlo0y5wIJI6-gaDzHZa8-ZULqq9ypgbAWrJ7waCgYKAdgSARISFQHGX2Mi0edxqQO-szLpEjKt-LrQ6Q0169

When I try to decode this I get the error that it doesn't consist of enough segments which indicates that the token is invalid.
Does someone know what I am doing wrong?
How can I get a valid access token so I can extract some user info from it.
This is my first post on SO so if I did something wrong or something is unclear, let me know!

Edit:
I found out that the access token can be used for subsequent calls to google's api. It doesn't contain user data itself and can't be decoded

How are you trying to decode the access_token? From the code I have it doesn't seem like decoding the access_token received in the response body is unnecessary.

I edited my post and showed the callback route function in which I decode the token.
